# when do we use : and when do we use = in html when we are using the attributes of a tag?

Tags: html, css

I am confused when it comes to using the attributes in CSS and HTML. When do we use : and when do we use = in HTML when we are using the attributes of a tag?

Comment: You need to learn the basic syntax of HTML and CSS.

Comment: `=` on attrs of the html tag ... `:` on each definition inside the `style` attribute

Comment: You _always_ use `=` for attributes in html and css. In CSS `:` is used for [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

Comment: : is for css-attributes.
= is for html Attributes.
Why is there any confusion?

Comment: HTML: attribute="value" - CSS: element.class#id[attribut=value]:pseudoselector { attribute:value; }

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the basics of a language that are explained in any book or online resource.

Answer (score 4):

Colons `:` are used to split CSS **style** property/value pairs. Equal signs `=` are used to split HTML **attribute** property/value pairs. This is simply a designation made at the language syntax level.

Although historically you could (and still can) control some elements of styling with HTML attributes:

```
<div color="red">red text</div>
```

vs.

```
<div style="color:red;">red text</div>
```

As time has progressed the movement of styling from HTML attributes to CSS has been made best practice. This aids the seperation of concerns between using HTML for content, CSS for styling and Javascript for functionality.

### More on Colons in CSS:

---

### Property / Value seperator

At a basic level, a colon is used to seperate a CSS property from its value, e.g:

`color:red;`

### Pseudo Selectors

You can denote a [**pseudo class**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), or [**pseudo element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) using a colon, such as for `:hover` or `::after`

> A CSS pseudo-class is a keyword added to selectors that specifies a
>   special state of the element to be selected. For example `:hover` will
>   apply a style when the user hovers over the element specified by the
>   selector.
>
> Just like pseudo-classes, pseudo-elements are added to selectors but
>   instead of describing a special state, they allow you to style certain
>   parts of a document. For example, the `::first-line` pseudo-element
>   targets only  the first line of an element specified by the selector.

### CSS XML/Namespaced Attribute selectors:

If you are styling an XML document, the colon is used to seperate the namespace from the property name in the CSS type selector, and should be [**escaped with a colon**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes):

```
description[xlink\:href="someimage.png"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

For XML attributes in HTML pages, you should [**declare the namespace in your CSS**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/#att-method) and replace with a pipe `|`

`@namespace xlink 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';`

```
description[xlink|href="someimage.png"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

In this case, the equals sign narrows the attribute value

Answer (score 2):

We use `=` in HTML, `:` in CSS.

**Example HTML:**

```
<div class="foo"></div>
```

**Example CSS:**

```
body {
  background: red;
}
```

---

However you can also embed CSS in HTML. Notice the usage of `:` and `=` in the following examples written in HTML.

**Example #1:** this is called inline styling.

```
<div class="foo" style="background: red;"></div>
```

**Example #2:**

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<style>
  body {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: i think OP is talking about (possibly) inline styling. maybe have an example of when to use both?

Comment: yeah the question is unclear; I guess his confusion is due to the inline styling, so hopefully more examples will make things clear

Answer (score 0):

in html tag you always use = between an attribute and his value.
A "special" attribute is style, in style value you use ccs syntax, that is styleProperties: value

```
<p style="text-align:right;color:red;">...</p>
```

ok?